# Not sure why my test is not working - 200 vs 400 status

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai, express-validator

I am trying to figure out why I can't pass this Chai test. I should get a 200 status message but I get a 400 (coming from the `if(!errors.isEmpty()`) in my InsuranceQuotesControllers.js file. Because `const errors` is not empty it returns the 400 status code. Any idea how I can solve this?

---

**Test.js**

```
const chai = require("chai")
const expect = chai.expect;
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const quote = require('../controllers/insuranceQuotesControllers');
const app = require('../app');
const pathUrl = "/api/v1/quote/car-insurance";

chai.use(require("chai-http"));

describe ('200 message status', () => {
    it('should return the 200 status message if the person is eligible', ()=>{
        chai.request('http://localhost:8080')
        .post(pathUrl)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .send({
                "car_value": 10000.00,
                "driver_birthdate": "17/11/1990"
              })
        .end((err, res) => {
          assert.equal(res.status, 200, "Status OK 200")
          // assert.equal(res.body.success, true)
          // assert.equal(res.body.message, "quote successfully computed")
          // assert.equal(res.body.data.eligible, false)
          // assert.equal(res.body.data.premiums, null)
        })
      });
})
```

---

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const insuranceQuoteRoutes = require("./routes/insuranceQuotes")

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use("/api", insuranceQuoteRoutes)

app.listen(8080)

module.exports = app
```

---

**insuranceQuotes.js**

```
const express = require("express")
// const {body} = require("express-validator");
const {check, validationResult} = require("express-validator");

const insuranceQuoteController = require("../controllers/insuranceQuotesControllers")

const router = express.Router()

//carDateRegex: https://www.regextester.com/99555
const carDateRegex = /^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}$/

// router.post("/v1/quote/car-insurance", [
//     body("car-value").isFloat(),
//     body("driver_birthdate").matches(carDateRegex)
// ], insuranceQuoteController.postInsuranceQuotes);

router.post("/v1/quote/car-insurance", [
    check("car-value").isFloat(),
    check("driver_birthdate").matches(carDateRegex)
], insuranceQuoteController.postInsuranceQuotes);

module.exports = router
```

---

**insuranceQuotesControllers.js**

```
const {check, validationResult} = require("express-validator");

exports.postInsuranceQuotes = (req,res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    const birthdateDriver = req.body.driver_birthdate;
    const ageDriver = driverAge(birthdateDriver);

    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({
            "success": false,
            "message": "parameters missing or incorrect values"
        })
    }

if(ageDriver < 18){
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "quote successfully computed",
        data: {
            eligible: false,
            premiums: null
        }
    })
} else if(ageDriver >= 18){
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "quote successfully computed",
        data: {
            eligible: true,
            premiums: {
                civil_liability: civilLiability(ageDriver),
                omnium: omnium()
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```